# Indent from current tab position in vim

Tags: vim

To indent a line in vim I can do `>>`. Is there a way to only indent from the current cursor position in a quick manner? What I am currently doing is:

- `i` (insert mode)
- `[tab]` (insert a tab)
- `[esc]` (go back to normal mode)

What would be the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On insert mode you can:

```
<Ctrl-t> .................... increase indenting
<Ctrl-d> .................... decrease indenting
```

To indent a whole paragraph you can:

```
>ap
```

To indent a single line:

```
>>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a command already existing to do that. But you can create your own mapping:

```
nnoremap >i i<TAB><ESC>
```

This will do what you want when you hit `>i` on normal mode

You'll find all the infos you need in vim documentation: type `:help key-mapping`